# How do I extract text fragments of a file using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to create a BASH script to extract fragments of text from a file that has many lines similar to this one:

```
"11","category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1","index.php?option=com_trombinoscopeextended&Itemid=125&lang=es&view=trombinoscope","251","0","0000-00-00","","","","","","","0"
```

From each line I only have to keep the:

```
category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1
```

The context can be deleted. I was trying using sed but I can't find a way to do that. I don't understand how create a command using the regular expression that I already have:

```
\w+(\/[\w-]+)+
```

I have been reading and  already tried this command and other similar ones but I don't know much about this:

```
cat file.txt | sed -i -E "s/\w+(\/[\w-]+)+"
```

That definitely is not working and I can't find a beginners guide on how to use sed and regular expressions.

Comment: Do you need the second column of each line or will your content be in different columns?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}' input`

Comment: @Jesse_b Thank you, that worked really well but it keeps the " symbol for each one. Is there a way to keep the same result without the "?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}' input | tr -d '"'`

Comment: @Jesse_b yes that's it, it isn't the approach that I was searching for but it worked great. How do we proceed to mark it as solved?

Comment: ... or `awk -F'","' '{print $2}'` if you know the fields are always quoted. If you *really* need to use sed, then `sed 's/[^,]*,"\([^",]*\)",.*/\1/'`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, the first one using awk worked but the second one using sed didn't. It does not find any match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a file like this is better done with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ print $2 }' file
```

or `cut`,

```
cut -d, -f 2 file
```

This would give you `"category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1"` (including the quotes) from the data that you supplied.

With `sed`, and utilizing the regular expression that you provided (but with `\w` replaced by `[[:alnum:]]`):

```
sed -E 's@.*,"([[:alnum:]]+(/[[:alnum:]-]+)+)",.*@\1@' file
```

This replaces the whole line with the bit that matches the regular expression within the first set of parentheses. This returns `category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1` for the data that you provided.

For more general CSV file parsing, including correctly handling quoting and fields that may contain commas or double quotes, use [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
csvcut -c 2 file
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your regex per se, just that you fell into the trap for the unwary. Inside of the [] the \w are two literals a backslash and a "w" and NOT a "\w" as one might think it to be or as in Perl, from where it's borrowed but not fully.

One way would be to lay out explicitly what is in a \w and then proceed:

```
sed -Ee '
    /\n/{P;D;}
    s|\w+(/[-_A-Za-z0-9]+)+|\n&\n|;D
'
```